# Android Vitals picking data from production-debug environment

Tags: android, google-play, android-vitals

I have 2 flavors

```
productFlavors {
    production {
        applicationId "com.signal"
    }
    development {
        applicationId "com.signal.staging"
    }
}
```

Now when I'm working in `developmentDebug` there are no recording done by Android Vitals.

However, when I switch to `productionDebug` Android Vitals records everything thinking it's a release build given the fact it is not.

How do I fix this?

Comment: From your question I don't understand the fix you want. It sounds like it is working properly - bug s in the production version get reported. What do you want to happen?

Comment: It is productionDebug not productionRelease which is the signed APK. I don't want it to collect info from a debug version

Comment: I've checked, this is a bug in Play. It is being worked on.

Comment: Does android vitals affect ASO?